# Shapeable image view - corner color - android

Tags: android, fragment, android-navigation-graph, shapeableimageview

[image]

In the second fragment I have used shapeable image view with shape appearance overlay to rounded. while applying material container transform, black corner are visible in shapeable image view. Help me how to remove the black corners.

Comment: maybe you could add some code to explain more of what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. I was setting background color to RED for example, but on lower android versions, corners got black just like in your case.

a workaround I came up with was to set background of ImageView using following lines of code:

```
imageView.background = ShapeDrawable(RectShape()).also {
    it.paint.color = myColor
}
```

Comment: No, it's just changing the background color of the circle, not the corners

Comment: my ImageView was circle, but the rectangle behind it was getting black, like in  your picture.